# Fitting shapes into a given area, finding best fit

Tags: python, geometry

How would you use python to work out how many blocks of a given size would fit into an area of a given size.

Lets say I have a rectangle of X x Y and I have an area of x1 x y1. How would I work out how many of the rectangle would fit into that area and what would be the best fit?

Comment: blocks can be rotated by 90 degrees only? should blocks always be rectangles?

Comment: yes about rotation. No, they an be any size,  L x H

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an instance of a [Packing problem](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Packing_problem). A nice algorithm for packing rectangles inside of a rectangle is described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/rectanglepacker.aspx). You'll need to write it in python, obviously.